# PHP to access run shell script

Tags: python, php, ubuntu

I have this PHP script that basically runs a shell script. The shell script takes a python file name main.py and gives output and stores it in a file after the output file gets to move to a different folder.
My PHP code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
  # This code will run if ?run=true is set.
  exec("/home/ubuntu/python/script.sh");
}
?>

<!-- This link will add ?run=true to your URL, myfilename.php?run=true -->
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>
```

Myscript code is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/python/main.py > /home/ubuntu/python/output/mainOut
mv /home/ubuntu/python/main.py /home/ubuntu/python/outputMain
```

My Script is working fine when I run it using command but with PHP it is giving me permission denied error.  I tried changing the user name or adding sudo to the script but it is not working. any suggestion will help.
this is my Error log:

mv: cannot move '/home/ubuntu/python/main.py' to '/home/ubuntu/python/outputMain/main.py': Permission denied

Comment: Your Apache probably runs as a separate user that doesn't have write permission in that directory.  You can try changing the group on the folder to Apache's group and changing the permissions to 775.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty workaround : `sudo chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/python -R`

If you want to solve it proper, here's my thinking:

- First check apache/nginx's running user & group
- Then check it's permission on such file/folder (that't not neccessary but it shows the problem more specific)
- Finally change the nginx-user's group like `usermod -aG GROUP USER` then `sudo chmod 775 DIR -R` (or you can make the permission more preciselly)

The diffrence of `777` and `775` is : `777` makes any user on your server could edit that file, when '775' only allowed owner and group members edit it.

Comment: thank you so much I did try changing the user from both apache and my home folder, but it wasn't working. then i ran chmodd 77 on every folder and file it was getting me the output but it wasn't moving the file.  your command "sudo chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/python -R " works like charm. I was only missing -R that made the whole thing work. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

If im not wrong you need to perform sudo chmod 755 or 777 on the .sh, and thats all.